# How to update archetype-catalog in Nexus repository

Tags: maven, nexus

I have a problem updating catalog. Into my Public Repository (its type is "Group") I proxy the repository
"liferay-ce" (https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/liferay-ce/).

If I click on "https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/liferay-ce/" I find the
original catalog "archetype-catalog.xml" which has some archetypes.

The "archetype-catalog.xml" sited at my Public Repository URL has an "archetype-catalog.xml" but
it doesn't contain the archetypes written into "liferay-ce" catalog.

I need to update my "archetype-catalog.xml" with the new archetypes contained into liferay-ce original
repository.

Have you any idea how to update my "archetype-catalog.xml"?

Answer (score 3):

The archetype-catalog.xml file is generated from the search indexes.  Run "update index" against your proxy repository, when this completes your local archetype-catalog.xml will have the entries from the "liferay-ce" repository.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tried to run "update index" against my "liferay-ce" proxy repository but I have the old catalog yet. I tried "Repair Index" too, but the issue persists.

Comment: Now the issue is fixed. The task "Update Repository Index" against all proxied repositories has been executed yesterday (4 AM) and I have archetype-catalog completed with new plugins (versione 6.2.1) now.